# HTML Table warning?

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

I am receiving a warning that says:

> Warning: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).

when I validate my HTML source page. I have tried to fix this but it seems to destroy how the table looks. Can anyone point me to how I would fix this error and keep the table image intact? Thank you!

Here is the table image currently:

[image: TABLE IMAGE]

here is my page source code:

```
<table class="tableStyle">
  <caption>Horizontal and Vertical Alignment</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">Cell Alignment With CSS</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="alignCentre" rowspan="4">Examples</th>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>Cell-1</th>
    <th>Cell-2</th>
    <th>Cell-3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="cellHeight">3</th>
    <td class="cellHeight vat hol">CSS</td>
    <td class="cellHeight hol">CSS</td>
    <td class="cellHeight vab hol">CSS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="cellHeight">4</th>
    <td class="cellHeight vat">CSS</td>
    <td class="cellHeight">CSS</td>
    <td class="cellHeight vab">CSS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="cellHeight">5</th>
    <td class="cellHeight vat hor">CSS</td>
    <td class="cellHeight hor">CSS</td>
    <td class="cellHeight vab hor">CSS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>

<!-- This is the second table of the page which contains the nested   table -->

<table class="tableStyle">
  <caption>Horizontal and Vertical Alignment</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Cell Alignment With CSS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="alignCentre" rowspan="2">Examples</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>

      <!-- This is the nested table & note the new class -->
      <table class="tableStyle2">
        <caption class="captionBottom">Nested Table</caption>
        <tr>
          <td>Row</td>
          <td>Cell-1</td>
          <td>Cell-2</td>
          <td>Cell-3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th class="cellHeight">3</th>
          <td class="cellHeight vat hol">CSS</td>
          <td class="cellHeight hol">CSS</td>
          <td class="cellHeight vab hol">CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="cellHeight">4</th>
          <td class="cellHeight vat">CSS</td>
          <td class="cellHeight">CSS</td>
          <td class="cellHeight vab">CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="cellHeight">5</th>
          <td class="cellHeight vat hor">CSS</td>
          <td class="cellHeight hor">CSS</td>
          <td class="cellHeight vab hor">CSS</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second table begins with a cell that spans two columns:

```
<!-- This is the second table of the page which contains the nested   table -->

<table class="tableStyle">
  <caption>Horizontal and Vertical Alignment</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Cell Alignment With CSS</th>
  </tr>
```

which is then followed by two single-column rows, one of which contains the nested table:

```
  <tr>
    <th class="alignCentre" rowspan="2">Examples</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>

      <!-- This is the nested table & note the new class -->
      <table class="tableStyle2">
```

Judging by your image, you probably meant to combine the two single-column rows into one. You probably don't need the `rowspan="2"` either, since the nested table is in its own cell which doesn't span multiple rows.

Here's how I would fix it:

```
<!-- This is the second table of the page which contains the nested   table -->

<table class="tableStyle">
  <caption>Horizontal and Vertical Alignment</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Cell Alignment With CSS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="alignCentre">Examples</th>
    <th>

      <!-- This is the nested table & note the new class -->
      <table class="tableStyle2">
```

The `tr` and `th` that contains the nested table are also missing their end tags. They don't strictly have to be there but you might want to add them so they're consistent with all your other table elements and you don't get confused as to why they're missing:

```
      </table>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i fixed it to your suggestion. Now get the following error:

Comment: Error: Table cell spans past the end of its row group established by a tbody element; clipped to the end of the row group.

From line 73, column 14; to line 74, column 48

      <tr>↩           <th class ="alignCentre" rowspan="2">Exampl